# My Android App ask location permission right after install (before launch) on some devices

Tags: android, android-permissions

I want my application to ask permission after the first launch. However on some devices, right after installation from play store it asks for a location permission. Customer wants me to get rid of this behavior. What might be the possible reason behind this behavior?

Comment: They're below Android 6 and the Play Store will warn the user since requesting permissions dynamically didn't exist then

Comment: That only way to get rid it is you avoid supporting devices below 6.0

Answer (score 0):

Permission fetching in android is of 3 types.

1. During installation from play store on devices upto Android API level 21 (Android 5.0 Lollipop) it just shows all the permissions mentioned in the `Manifest.xml` file together, and no separate pop-ups arise requesting the user to provide permissions.
2. During installation from play store on devices on Android API level 22 (Android 5.1 Lollipop) separate pop-ups arise for each permission.
3. FROM API level 23 (Android 6.0 Marshmallow), the devices support run-time permissions, where we could fetch permission on any activity where the respective feature is about to be used by the user.

You can read on these links on how to use them efficiently:

1. [link1](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/permissions/overview)
2. [link2](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting)
3. [link3](https://developer.android.com/distribute/best-practices/develop/runtime-permissions)